# MongoDB with Node.js can't find one other collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've done two collections before "article" and "news" and it all works...
If i want to do other collection mongo cant find it

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var calendarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
create_date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
});

var Calendar = module.exports = mongoose.model('calendar',calendarSchema);

module.exports.getCalendar = function(callback, limit){
Calendar.find(callback).limit(limit);

}
});
```

Calendar.find() returns empty array.
if i change mongoose.model to " news" it works

Comment: Mongoose is expecting `"calendars"` as the name of the collection. Perhaps it's called `"calendar"` in your database? If so use the third argument on the model definition `mongoose.model('calendar', calendarSchema, 'calendar')` which specifies a specific collection name rather than the pluralized default.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with commands if you don't have robomongo,

```
 >mongo
//Mongodb
    >show dbs  
//It shows the database
    >use yourdbname 
//type your db name
    >show collections 
//It shows all collections what you have done so far
```

Comment: yee i know with commands i cant find "calendar" collection and return data and all works

Comment: check it out clearly. you said that, Calendar.find() it returns empty array. If the fields are not in your collections its only returns empty array.

Comment: I had to change collection name from calendar to calendars.

Comment: everything works, tkanks all

Comment: yeah. if you give singluar, mongodb converts into plural.